# Intellij IDEA 14.1 makes whole project read only

Tags: intellij-idea

Sometimes for some reason, Intellij locks down my whole project. All folders become read only and I have to manually click on each folder and make it writable again, but this only lasts whilst the project is open. If I reopen the project the folders are read only again. This is massively frustrating. Looking at windows folder security rights everything seems fine and I am able to manually create files, but when I create anything using Intellij in said project folders it doesnt want to let me. Anyone maybe had the same problem and know what might be the cause of this or how I can remidy this.

Comment: I wish there was a feature that lets me lock a module so i cant accidentally make changes

Comment: I actually wish this was a feature toggle provided by Intellij so that you can make the entire project read-only on demand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that Google drive is the culprit. It somehow marks the folders read only for Intellij

Comment: It's true, but how do we solve it...?

Comment: I dropped using Drive for keeping my code in the cloud. Now using Bitbucket to store my code